Android production build failing with Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED
This is the error I'm getting.
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage

Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest

Debug variant works, but release variant is throwing the error above.
Have tried increasing memory with org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m.
What does the error mean and what could be the problem?

Do you have all the required proguard rules for all your libraries? Specifically check for okhttp, retrofit, and others. Otherwise please provide your build gradle with the dependencies and current proguard rules configuration.
